# Better ways for connection initialization in Datastax Astra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-astra

I have some queries regarding Datastax Astra.

The connection initialization of Datastax Astra via the secure bundle is relatively slow. Is there any other way via which we can do connection initialization faster?

Also, what are some of the best practices to handle the connection to Datastax Astra to prevent timeouts

I really appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Comment: Define slow? How do you measure slow? Could you showcase some metrics? How does your driver configuration look like? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the slowness you perceive is when you're running your app on your laptop/desktop and connecting to your Astra DB over the internet. In this scenario, the network latency is unavoidable and is expected.

However, this is not typical for production deployments. As a rule, enterprises use private endpoints (also known as private links) which are dedicated connections between app instances and Astra DB in the same region. Since both the app and DB are in the same region, it doesn't suffer from the same network latency issue as connecting over public networks.

Private endpoints also have the added benefit of strong security since the DB is not exposed to the internet. Cheers!