# Getting connection timeouts on application startup

Tags: node.js, cassandra, datastax-astra, datastax-node-driver

We have a staging instance of our web app that connects to DataStax Astra PAYG using NodeJS driver.

Sometimes when the app has been idle and is first accessed we get repeated instances of this error for around a minute, then the errors stop and normal function resumes.  We have set consistency to cassandra.types.consistencies.localQuorum

```
Server timeout during read query at consistency LOCAL_QUORUM (1 replica(s) responded over 2 required)
```

I'd just like to understand if our Astra database may require time to warm up if it has been idle.

We occasionally during what I'll call warm up, we may also experience connection timeout issues:

```
"{\n  labels: [ 'ERROR' ],\n  message: '\"[SERVER][FATAL] Restarting due to: [x.x.x.x:9042] Request execution failed, took 7000 ms (request size 52 bytes): SELECT * FROM x WHERE name = ? [x@x.x]; error: OperationTimedOutError: The host 40.82.203.91:29042 did not reply before timeout 7000 ms
```

For clarity, under normal operation we not see these errors.

Can anyone comment?

Rod

Comment: We are not currently using a private endpoint.  This is on our TODO list.  Our app is co-located in the same Azure datacenter as the Astra instance.  It may be (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74748017/better-ways-for-connection-initialization-in-datastax-astra) that using a private endpoint could reduce latency.

Answer (score 1):

The symptoms you described indicate to me that you are using a "free" account.

If that's the case, your [Astra DB](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-astra) gets hibernated (or "parked") when it's been idle for some time. When your application connects to the cluster on startup, that operation "wakes" the DB from hibernation. This is the reason you don't see the errors when the application has been operating as normal.

If you're doing a proof-of-concept (PoC), I would recommend getting in contact with the team at DataStax using [the live chat functionality on the bottom right of the Astra web UI](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/get-support.html). They will be happy to talk about your use case and provide free credits so your Astra DB does not get hibernated. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you. I am not on a free plan - I am on PAYG (paid) plan, but what you describe is consistent with my experience.  Can you confirm if paid PAYG Astra databases will also get parked if idle?

Comment: Can you clarify where the live chat appear (screenshot please).  I don't see it at bottom right of screen in Astra portal...

Comment: Chat is accessible within the documentation window - e.g. https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/astra-faq.html

Comment: It's the big, smiley face on the bottom right of every screen. It's hard to miss. Cheers!

Comment: Where?   https://c31875ed1cc774c5d631-488be2b0fc4000c42fa0c776dbc97323.ssl.cf4.rackcdn.com/2023/4/5e87aab0-f386-11ed-8fea-000000000000/image.png

Comment: Solved,,, uBlock browser extension was blocking it... wasn't expecting that.